# How do you completely purge Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm working on Spring Java micro-services using Apache Kafka for messaging. At times I want to completely reset my Kafka cluster (Zookeeper and broker) so that I know I have a clean slate to test with.  However, my broker still seems to know a lot about things that should have been delete.

The environment is Windows 10 and I'm running Kafka v2.12.2 from Cygwin.

Here's my current process for resetting my Kafka setup:

1. Stop the broker
2. Stop Zookeeper
3. Delete the data directory
4. Restart Zookeeper
5. Restart the broker

At this point I see the broker logging showing references to loading offsets and consumer groups.

For example:

```
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,118] INFO Replica loaded for partition __consumer_offsets-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,120] INFO [Partition __consumer_offsets-0 broker=0] __consumer_offsets-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

And:

```
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,171] INFO Replica loaded for partition __consumer_offsets-23 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,172] INFO [Partition __consumer_offsets-23 broker=0] __consumer_offsets-23 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,174] INFO Replica loaded for partition __consumer_offsets-1 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,174] INFO [Partition __consumer_offsets-1 broker=0] __consumer_offsets-1 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

And:

```
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,304] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-46 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,304] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-49 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,304] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-41 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,305] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-44 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,305] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-47 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,305] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-10-23 09:38:49,306] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-4 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

EDIT #1:

Below are a couple of lines from my property files. If I delete 'C:\tool\kafka\data' I'll still see similar logging to the above.

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=C:/tools/kafka/data/zookeeper
```

**server.properties**

```
log.dirs=C:/tools/kafka/data/kafka-logs
```

Comment: Have you deleted topic metadata from Zookeeper?

Comment: "Kafka v2.12.2" does not exist... If you want to start fresh and not worry about files to go clean up, Docker is a good way to get that

Comment: delete the directory configured as `log.dirs` in kafka and `dataDir` in zookeeper with ALL the kafka and zookeeper instances down

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous As far as I am aware Zookeeper keeps all it's data in the file system so stopping the service and deleting that file system should have the same effect, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 Take a look at the download page: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: @Paizo I made an edit to my OP as I've tried what you suggested already

Comment: If this is for testing purposes, I would use docker and i.e. https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/. Then all you need to do to wipe everything id to shut down the docker image and it will start fresh when started up again

Comment: What about it? ***2.0.0** is the latest release. The current stable version is **2.0.0***. I think you are conflating the Scala version with the actual Kafka version. In other words, you have Kafka 2.0, which is built with Scala 2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a process still connected to the cluster and this caused the offsets to be rebuilt once the clustered started.

Make 110% sure every process had finished and deleting the data directory worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Delete these files created from dataDir and log.dirs by the following properties files

**zookeeper.properties**

`dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper`

**server.properties**

`log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs`